# How do I make a fingerprint password? Lenovo Thinkpad X300

Tags: password, fingerprint-reader

I have a Lenovo X300 and it comes with a fingerprint scanner on the bottom right of my computer. There doesn't seem to be any password settings so How do I set it up to unlock the computer at login?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/511876/how-do-i-install-a-fingerprint-reader-on-lenovo-thinkpad ?

Answer (score 0):

From [Login using fingerprint reader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111334/login-using-fingerprint-reader) by @Ringtail

> This is available in the repositories as well a sourcefourge
>
> libpam-thinkfinger
>
> ThinkFinger is a driver for the UPEK/STMicroelectronics fingerprint
>   reader. The device is usually found either as a standalone USB device,
>   built into USB keyboards or built into laptops (usually from Dell,
>   IBM/Lenovo and Toshiba).
>
> pam_thinkfinger is a Pluggable Authentication Module that allows the
>   user authenticates through his fingerprint.
>
> The recommended package thinkfinger-tools can be used to acquire,
>   verify and automatically store user fingerprints.
>
> Homepage: http://thinkfinger.sourceforge.net
>
> PAM wiki